# create-react-app defaulting to class based components on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried using create-react-app on a ubuntu machine and it seems to be defaulting to older class based components... is there anyway to change this behavior?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have tried the following to setup the app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

```
npm i -g create-react-app
create-react-app my app
```

`node -v` output is `v16.18.0`
`npm -v` output is `8.19.2`

When using create-react-app the following message is displayed after the project folder is created:

```
Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6 to get supported tools in new projects.
```

node is installed with snap

Comment: `node -v` `npm -v `

Comment: `node -v` = `v16.18.0`,`npm -v` = `8.19.2`

Comment: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: I tried `sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app ; npx create-react-app my-app` and it gives the same outcome as before.

Comment: You can try `npx -v` but I have no other idea what else could be wrong

Comment: `npx -v` shows same version as `npm -v`

Comment: did you install react-scripts globally?

Comment: nope. I will give that a try

Comment: Does your npm point to a different npm server?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: I tried installing react-scripts but made now difference

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may have been `nvm` was defaulting to an older version of node, overriding other installations. I was able to sort it out by setting up nvm using the following steps:

1. In your terminal, run `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash`
2. Confirm the install with `nvm ls`
3. Install a version of node with `nvm install v<version>` eg. `nvm install v16.18`
4. Make it your default version with `nvm alias default <version>` eg. `nvm alias default 16.18` and restart your shell

After getting `nvm` to work create-react-app started behaving itself!